# Python: do I need a Singleton?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, design-patterns

I've multiple instanciated logger classes in `logger.py` which I import in multiple other modules.

**logger.py**

```
class Logger:
    def __init__(self, name='default'):
        # create a Logger with custom handlers
        # ...

main_logger = Logger('main_logger')
another_topic_logger = Logger('another_topic_logger')
```

**module_a.py**

```
from logger import main_logger
main_logger.info('hello!')
```

How does Python handle it in the background? Do I need a Singleton wrapper or is that just fine?

Comment: You don't really get to tell people, "this question is on topic". That's entirely up to the people reading the question. I've removed that bit because I think it's likely to prejudice people against your question.

Comment: you could try to use `id(main_logger)` in modules to see if you use the same instance. Usually Python remeber imported module and it doesn't import it again but it use aready imported code - but I'm not sure if it is true if you import the same module in other modules.

Comment: Maybe I'm being misled by the name, but why are you defining your own `Logger` class instead of using the `logging` module? (Which, by the way, doesn't make you instantiate *its* `Logger` class directly; you call a module level function named `getLogger` which, based on the argument, will either create a new instance or return an existing instance.)

Comment: @larsks it wasn't meant to dictate an opinion, but to clarify that I thought about it before asking the question here, as it can be easily misinterpreted.

Comment: Also, you have multiple instances of your `Logger` class; another module importing only one of those instances doesn't make anything a singleton.

Comment: @chepner the `class Logger` uses `logging.getLogger()`. The goal by this extra layer of abstraction is to avoid redundancy by having all the handlers in one file.

Comment: @chepner What do you recommend? I think I'm not following the pythonic way but I hope the idea is clear.

Comment: I don't see any problem with what you have right now. `logger.py` creates several instances of `Logger`, and makes them available for use by other modules.

Comment: @chepner Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It is just fine. But why you need different logger classes?

In python, different loggers could be the same class's instance with different logger name.

Refer to https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html

You could set different handlers to different log instances.

Usually, we create and use loggers in this way:

**module_a.py**

```py
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('module_a')
fh = logging.FileHandler('spama.log')
logger.addHandler(fh)

Class foo:
    pass
```

**module_b.py**

```py
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('module_b')
fh = logging.FileHandler('spamb.log')
logger.addHandler(fh)

Class bar:
    pass
```

If you want to config a lot of loggers in one file:

**log_config.py**

```py
# You could create your loggers anywhere, but configure them in one file

import logging.config


LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'filters': {
        'special': {
            '()': 'project.logging.SpecialFilter',
            'foo': 'bar',
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'null': {
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'class':'django.utils.log.NullHandler',
        },
        'console':{
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'class':'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple'
        },
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
            'filters': ['special']
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'module_a': {
            'handlers':['null'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level':'INFO',
        },
        'module_b': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'myproject.custom': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'mail_admins'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'filters': ['special']
        }
    }
}

logging.config.dictConfig(LOGGING)
```

**main.py**

```py
import module_a
import module_b
import log_config

module_a.logger.debug("something")
```

BTW, if you get logger with same name in different python files, they are exactly the same instance. In fact `getLogger` function means `get or create a logger with the given name`.

Comment: Thanks! I've multiple `logging.getLogger()` with different handlers, depending on the topic. Some log files are allowed to grow to 10 MB, some only to 1 MB. Some save the `debug()` output, some don't. My goal is to have all this configuration done one time in one file.

Comment: @Mr.B. Oh, I know what your want, wait one minute or just take a look at https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#an-example-dictionary-based-configuration